# Can nested function calls in return statement lead to stack-use-after-scope error?

Tags: c++

Here's a code snippet:

```
inline length::len Get(const ABC& a, const XYZ& x)
{
    return length::len{x.Poly().Line(a.Pose()).value()};
}

void MyClass::MyMethod()
{
  // Get max distance
  result_ = Get(*a_, *x_);
}
```

- Can the above lead to stack-use-after-scope error?
- Is there any standard way to have such nested function calls in a return statement?

Comment: Difficult to know without a [mre]

Comment: That is the "standard way". If it has any problems, your problem lies elsewhere.